# Replace single quote from Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my below code I want to replace single quote with some other say "&" but it's not reflecting.

```
if(this.selectdFilterValues.Any(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains("'")))
{
    this.selectdFilterValues.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.Replace("'", "&"));
}
```

Also I want to handle this single quote as when it contains single quote my below JS function does not hit

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", 
    "<script type='text/javascript'>initViz('" + 
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.selectdFilterValues) + 
    "');</script>", false);
```

Comment: When you're making `this.selectdFilterValues.Select(kvp => kvp.Value.Replace("'", "&"))` here works LINQ, and the result must be realized via foreach loop or somethink.

Answer (score 4):

Using `.Select` does not modify the original collection in place. It projects them into a new IEnumerable which you can use however you wish. Right now you're just throwing the result away. You can instead use them to create a new Dictionary:

`this.selectedFilterValues = this.selectdFilterValues.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Replace("'", "&"));`

Or, if you're okay with using an iterative approach instead of a functional one you can simply loop through the Dictionary using a ForEach and overwriting the old values.

Comment: ERROR:'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Replace'

Comment: If you're getting that error it means your Dictionary has boolean values, not string values. I literally took that from your own code snippet in the original post so you'll have to tweak it if your code snippet is not accurate

Comment: @ShwetaGupta if your values are of type `bool`, then your question makes no sense to begin with.